# Why won't new project templates install correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, silverlight-5.0

I've just installed Visual Studio 2010 (as well as SP1) yet for some reason I am unable to install the ASP.NET MVC 4 or Silverlight 5 SDK templates properly.  I can see a single template with the *old* Visual Basic module type icon as shown below:

[image: Project templates example]

My issue comes when loading a project from another PC, or even attempting to create a new project--it seems as if it can't find the template:

[image: Project type not supported]

My project type GUIDs do appear to be correct in correlating to a WebAPI / C# application:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

I'm also experiencing the same issues with the Silverlight 5 SDK, yet there I don't even see the option to create a Silverlight app--only the following templates are available:

- Silverlight Unit Test Application
- Silverlight 3D Application
- Silverlight 3D Library

I would appreciate it if anyone had any idea what's going wrong!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by completely uninstalling Visual Studio SP1 then uninstalling the complete Visual Studio package.  After this, the issue was fixed by a reinstall.